# Phabricator not sending emails

Tags: phabricator

I've gotten Phabricator running, but I'm not receiving emails from the UI. What I've tried so far:

- Using PHPMailer - I get the test email using `./bin/mail send-test`, but when I send the user welcome email through the UI, nothing gets sent out
- Using Mailgun - I also get the test email using `./bin/mail send-test`, and the Mailgun interface shows emails delivered. However no email gets sent when requested through the interface
- I see emails in list-outbound

At this point I'm thinking Phabricator is using different settings for the send-test vs. the UI. Any pointers?

Comment: You can check the PHPMailer configuration in config/PHPMailer in Phabricator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fixed it with a restart. Seems like a number of settings in Phabricator need restarts, but unfortunately the UI doesn't make that clear.

Comment: Phabricator does not need any reboot. Maybe your daemons was stopped, and with a restart you started them. In the future, just check the status of your daemon.

Answer (score 1):

If everything works from command line, but nothing works from the web user interface, just double-check the status of your Phabricator daemon. It must be running.

https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/managing_daemons/